# Only working days and remove weekend and holidays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, date, days

I am trying to format only the working days, removing Saturday, Sunday and holidays.

I found this function "function day_holiday()" in the "Stackoverflow" on holidays in my home country.

I created this script in php below in my knowledge

```
//-------------------------HOLIDAY--------------
function day_holiday($ano = null){
    if ($ano === null){
        $ano = intval(date('Y'));
    }
    $pascoa     = easter_date($ano);
    $dia_pascoa = date('j', $pascoa);
    $mes_pascoa = date('n', $pascoa);
    $ano_pascoa = date('Y', $pascoa);

    $holiday = array(
        mktime(0, 0, 0, 1,  1,   $ano),
        mktime(0, 0, 0, 4,  21,  $ano),
        mktime(0, 0, 0, 5,  1,   $ano),
        mktime(0, 0, 0, 9,  7,   $ano),
        mktime(0, 0, 0, 10,  12, $ano),
        mktime(0, 0, 0, 11,  2,  $ano),
        mktime(0, 0, 0, 11, 15,  $ano),
        mktime(0, 0, 0, 12, 25,  $ano),

        mktime(0, 0, 0, $mes_pascoa, $dia_pascoa - 48,  $ano_pascoa),
        mktime(0, 0, 0, $mes_pascoa, $dia_pascoa - 47,  $ano_pascoa), 
        mktime(0, 0, 0, $mes_pascoa, $dia_pascoa - 2 ,  $ano_pascoa), 
        mktime(0, 0, 0, $mes_pascoa, $dia_pascoa     ,  $ano_pascoa),
        mktime(0, 0, 0, $mes_pascoa, $dia_pascoa + 60,  $ano_pascoa),
    );
    sort($holiday);
    return $holiday;
}
//-------------------------HOLIDAY--------------


//-------------SCRIPT-------------
function formatDate($startDate,$days) {

    $holiday = day_holiday();
    foreach ($holiday as $allholiday){

        if($startDate==date('d-m-Y',$allholiday)){
            $newDate=date('d-m-Y', strtotime("+1 days",strtotime($startDate)));
        }else{
            $newDate = date('d-m-Y', strtotime("{$startDate} +{$days} weekdays"));
        }
    }

    return $newDate;
}

$sales = "19-01-2019"; //19 and Saturday is jumping for Monday 21 second
/*
These are some holidays.
01-01-2019
04-03-2019
05-03-2019
19-04-2019
21-04-2019
21-04-2019
01-05-2019
*/

echo "Start: ",date("d-m-Y", strtotime($sales)),"<br />";

echo formatDate($sales, "0");
```

The problem is removing only on Saturdays and Sundays. The holidays are not being removed. What is missing? can someone help me? If you have a more dynamic script you could post here.

Comment: So, you say `04-03-2019` is a holiday, but I don't see it defined in your array? Saying that, it appears your issue is probably because you don't `break` the `foreach` loop once you've found it's a holiday, so the loop continues, overriding `$newDate`.

Comment: @Jon Stirling  It's coming in an array, I'm trying to remove the holidays and weekend. It looks like it's not doing this, I'm looking for help even a better script than this one.

Comment: I've updated previous comment with what I think the issue is. If you're looking for a replacement script, SO isn't the place :)

Comment: @JonStirling I can try to use the script, but I do not know where I am wrong, if you can help me, thank you very much

Comment: I already told you, you need a `break` when you've found a matching holiday date.

Comment: @JonStirling Okay, how can I pause?

Comment: Pause? Pause what? What would you pause for?

Comment: @JonStirling Would you use a switch case in PHP? http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.break.php

Comment: In your case, probably not. But there's no reason you couldn't.

Comment: @JonStirling How would you do it?

Comment: That's much too broad a question. What you have seems to work, if you add the `break`, so speculation on how I would do it seems unnecessary.

Comment: @JonStirling I will think and research if you find something interesting put there, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably a more robust way of doing what you want. The function creates a [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object from the start time, then compares the timestamp to see if

1. It is in the `$holiday` array; or
2. It is a Saturday or Sunday (day of week = 0 or 6)

If none of these conditions are true, the loop exits and the date is returned. Otherwise, the date is incremented by 1 day until a date is found that matches all the conditions (i.e. Monday to Friday, and not a holiday).

```
function formatDate($startDate) {
    $holiday = day_holiday();
    $start = date_create_from_format('d-m-Y H:i:s', $startDate . ' 00:00:00');
    do {
        $ts = (int)$start->format('U');
        $dow = (int)$start->format('w');
        if (!in_array($ts, $holiday) && $dow != 0 && $dow != 6) break;
        $start->modify('+1 day');
    }
    while (true);
    return $start->format('d-m-Y');
}
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/maUsU)

Comment: This script is perfect, I will use it in my project. I was very grateful that good that there are people like you, thank you. Peace :-)